# Unescaped commandline content in fish shell

Tags: command-line, shell, fish, escaping

Is there a way to get the unescaped content of command line in fish? I mean if command line is like ...

```
$ ls 'foo' "bar"
```

... the desired output would be `ls 'foo' "bar"`.

The `commandline` fish command does return the command line but it escapes the content automatically. i.e. `ls foo bar`.

In the manual I didn't find any switches to suppress this behavior.

Context: I am trying to emulate bash's `ctrl-x ctrl-e` which allows editing the command line content in an editor. For that I need the unescaped content of the command line.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out fish 2.3 fixes the printing behavior and leaves the command-line unescaped. In fish 2.3 `commandline -b` prints the command-line unescaped.

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer your question I think, but I found this online somewhere

```
function bind_edit_commandline
    set -l tmp (mktemp /tmp/fish-fc.XXXXXX)
    commandline > $tmp
    eval $EDITOR $tmp
    commandline -r ""
    cat $tmp | while read -l cmd; commandline -a "$cmd" ""; end 
    rm $tmp
end
```

And I like <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>, so

```
bind \ev bind_edit_commandline
```

Comment: Thank you, but as you mentioned this doesn't solve the escaping problem.

Comment: I haven't looked at the source code but it wouldn't surprise me if this is a problem that can't be solved the way you want.